# Can I change all math output to use monospaced text?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, typewriter

Is there any way of modifying the preamble, so instead of typing

```
$\mathtt{x}$ ...
\begin{eqnarray}
    \mathtt{y} & \mathtt{=} & \mathtt{z^\pi}
\end{eqnarray}
```

I can omit the \mathtt{...} commands?

Comment: Have a look at the `\everymath` command, and also [eqnarray-vs-align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align) for reasons to avoid `eqnarray`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can add

```
 \everymath{\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}
```

to the document preamble (or the part of the document where you need this)

and

```
 \everydisplay{\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}
```

if you need display math as well.

---

In then in addition you may need to force the initialisation by putting

```
\setbox0\hbox{$ $}
```

in the preamble otherwise the *first* expression may not be initialised correctly. This just makes an empty math expression on a box and discards it to avoid the problem.

Comment: This is great, thank you. How would I reset the presentation of math LaTeX for later use? E.g. if I want monospace for some math blocks in a document using your solution, but want the default math presentation for everywhere else in the document?