# Can I set it so that math mode has uppercase letters not italicized?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, capitalization, italic

Is there a way to set it so that math mode *automatically* stops italicizing upper-case letters? That is, so that `$U$` produces the effect of what is now `$\mathrm{U}$`? I am using computer modern. I am aware other fonts have this option, but I would like to do it in computer modern. However, it would be great if some solution is font-independent, so that I can switch between them and keep this setting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use \mathrm by default](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15058/use-mathrm-by-default)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: This asks only for capital letters.

Comment: @morbusg: +1 ;-) I misunderstood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### For LaTeX, see Philippe Goutet's answer!

For **Plain TeX** the definition could be:

```
\mathcode`A="7041
\mathcode`B="7042
\mathcode`C="7043
% ...
\mathcode`Z="705A
$ ABC\dots Z $
\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you're using LaTeX and not plain TeX, you should prefer `\DeclareMathSymbol` to `\mathcode`. You can even avoid giving explicitly the position of the uppercase letters in the font by using `` `A `` instead of the corresponding number `41`:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{A}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{B}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{C}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{D}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{E}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{F}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{G}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`G}
\DeclareMathSymbol{H}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`H}
\DeclareMathSymbol{I}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`I}
\DeclareMathSymbol{J}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`J}
\DeclareMathSymbol{K}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`K}
\DeclareMathSymbol{L}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`L}
\DeclareMathSymbol{M}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`M}
\DeclareMathSymbol{N}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`N}
\DeclareMathSymbol{O}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`O}
\DeclareMathSymbol{P}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`P}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Q}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`Q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{R}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`R}
\DeclareMathSymbol{S}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`S}
\DeclareMathSymbol{T}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`T}
\DeclareMathSymbol{U}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`U}
\DeclareMathSymbol{V}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`V}
\DeclareMathSymbol{W}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`W}
\DeclareMathSymbol{X}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`X}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Y}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`Y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Z}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`Z}
```

Comment: Seeing how it must eventually expand out to the same thing, I cannot see how it would be preferrable to say the same thing with more letters?

Comment: @morbusg: when you use LaTeX, you should always prefer the LaTeX syntax, even if it's longer to type. There's a reason why the LaTeX team made the `\DeclareMathSymbol` command instead of directly using `\mathcode`.

Comment: That's what I was getting at; do you know what is that reason?

Comment: @morbusg: LaTeX does dynamic math font assignation. The fam number might not even exist before the first formula using a given alphabet (e.g. `\mathtt`; that's the reason for the convolutions in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64257) and can change from one document to another (depending on the loading order of packages). Here, as the roman family number is always `0`, it's not that important, but if you wanted to use the ttfamily for the math, using plain tex syntax would not be reliable (the number you choose could either already be taken or overwritten later).

Comment: @morbusg: and if you use xelatex, `\fam0` can have surprises: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{fontspec}\begin{document}Character 0A is $\mathchar"700A$ in fam0 but $\mathchar"740A$ in fam4.\end{document}`

Comment: Hmm, I see, thanks. How do we promote your answer instead of mine? Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @morbusg: you've clearly labeled your answer for use with plain tex, so there's no ambiguity. Deleting your answer would be a mistake as it's always informative to know how things work with plain tex.