# Unicode text in minted source-code listing fails on certain characters

Tags: unicode, minted

I'm currently writing a small mathematical paper and have lots of unicode in my source-code - e.g.:

```
function y(
    ::Vector{<:Number},
    Φ::(T where T <: Function),
    ::Vector{<:Number})::(T where T <: Number)
    Σ(1, size()[1], j->[j] * Φ(j, ))
end
```

The problem I'm now having is that I (for example) can't get it to render the (U+1D430) and . I get the following in my build-log:

```
Missing character: There is no  in font Droid Sans Mono/OT:mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font Droid Sans Mono/OT:mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font Droid Sans Mono/OT:mapping=tex-text;!
```

and no matter what font I use it's this way. I'm 100% certain that my font (usually Fira Code) does support the character because it's also what I run in my source-code editor and there the characters show up just fine. I also made sure to test all the fallback fonts(hence the error message shows Droid Sans Mono) - but to no avail.

Does anyone have an idea on what else I could try to fix this?

EDIT: minimal working example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text, Scale=0.90,]{Fira Code}
%\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text, Scale=0.90,]{Droid Sans Mono}

\begin{document}
  \begin{minted}{Julia}
      """Linear Regression
      # Args:
          : Parameters
          Φ(j, ): Basis function of type (Int, Vector{T}) -> T
          : Input vector
      """
      function y(
        ::Vector{<:Number},
        Φ::(T where T <: Function),
        ::Vector{<:Number})::(T where T <: Number)
          Σ(1, size()[1], j->[j] * Φ(j, ))
      end
  \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image: Fauty Output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) showing the problem? It'll be easier to help you.

Comment: @AlainRemillard Thanks - totally forgot about the example - I just edited it in

Comment: I don't think that fira code has the chars. If I try `{\ttfamily    }` I get clear missing char messages in the log. Your editor it probably using a fall back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your aim is to print boldface **w** and **x**.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmonofont{FiraMono}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  Scale=0.9,
]

\newunicodechar{}{\textbf{w}}
\newunicodechar{}{\textbf{x}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{Julia}
"""Linear Regression
# Args:
    : Parameters
    Φ(j, ): Basis function of type (Int, Vector{T}) -> T
    : Input vector
"""
function y(
  ::Vector{<:Number},
  Φ::(T where T <: Function),
  ::Vector{<:Number})::(T where T <: Number)
    Σ(1, size()[1], j->[j] * Φ(j, ))
end
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: works like a charm - thanks :D I had looked for something like that but couldn't find it

Comment: Optimal solution for a presentation. The resulting PDF produces a bold `w` (U+0077) rather than  (U+1D430 mathematical small w), so semantic meaning of the symbol is lost in copy-paste. Mapping, or monospacing a math font in text mode, might provide ways to keep the meaning, if desired.

Comment: @Cicada Do you know about a monospaced Unicode math font?

Comment: @egreg, I haven't come across any yet, but I'll have a look. There is also a workaround that might work, perhaps: typeset every glyph 1em wide.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments.

A general text font is unlikely to be going to cover the 996 symbols of the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols code block in Unicode, let alone all the operators etc. A math font with Basic Latin glyphs, with everything in text mode (i.e., direct Unicode input) looks like it could work, if you make it the main font. All glyphs will print 'as-is', i.e., like ordinary glyphs, even though some are bold or not, some are italic or upright, some are sans or serif, etc. `Asana Math` and `Latin Modern Math` are two fonts like that. There are probably more. The reason is that the MAS defines 13 Latin alphabets, 5 and a bit Greek ones, and 5 types of Digits. The MAS is independent of the Basic Latin block, where the 'text' A-Z, a-z letters are.

[image: symbols as text]

I don't have shell-escape, so `minted` is inactive and I made manual line feeds.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Scale=0.90,]{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
%  \begin{minted}{Julia}
      """Linear Regression \\
      \# Args:\\
: Parameters\\
Φ(j, ): Basis function of type (Int, Vector{T}) $\to$ T\\
: Input vector\\
      """\\
      function y(\\
        ::Vector{<:Number},\\
        Φ::(T where T <: Function),\\
        ::Vector{<:Number})::(T where T <: Number)\\
          Σ(1, size()[1], j->[j] * Φ(j, ))\\
      end\\
%  \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

If `minted` is the driver of the question, we will need to find a mono math font with basic Latin (alternatively, can `minted` accept $...$ math mode?).

=====

**Edited to add**:

egreg's `\newunicodechar` is quite powerful. In effect, it maps A to B: ↦, where  is a glyph/character and  is arbitrary code.

This in turn allows math mode material (like $\to$, attached to an arbitrary glyph) to be inserted into the `minted` output. $..$ material directly inside `minted` prints verbatim, otherwise.

As well as non-ASCII mathematical symbols and operators.

[image: arrow and symbols]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmonofont{Fira Mono}[
  Scale=0.9,
]

\newfontface\fmxm{XITS Math}[Colour=blue]

\newunicodechar{}{{\fmxm }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\fmxm }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\fmxm }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\fmxm }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\fmxm }}
\newunicodechar{∗}{{\fmxm ∗}}

\newunicodechar{}{{\fmxm $\to$}}


\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{Julia}
"""Linear Regression
# Args:
     : Parameters
    (, ): Basis function of type (Int, Vector{T})  T
    : Input vector
"""
function y(
  ::Vector{<:Number},
  ::(T where T <: Function),
  ::Vector{<:Number})::(T where T <: Number)
    (1, size()[1], [] ∗ (, ))
end
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

A random Anatolian hieroglyph, , is being used to carry the $\to$ into the output.

=====

**Edit 2**

Using code from here ([How to change math font to monospace, only inside \texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64251/how-to-change-math-font-to-monospace-only-inside-texttt)), and using `newunicodechar` as a key-value mechanism, gives:

[image: ttmath]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\ttmath}{%
  \everymath{%
    {\scriptstyle\mathtt{}}%
    {\scriptscriptstyle\mathtt{}}%
    \mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}}
\newcommand{\val}[1]{\bgroup\ttmath\texttt{#1}\egroup}

\newunicodechar{}{\ensuremath{x^2 + y^2 = z^2}; \val{1\ensuremath{\ensuremath{\cdot}10\ensuremath{^{-6}}}} (\ensuremath{a_0}, \ensuremath{m_{\text{e}}})}
\newunicodechar{}{$\alpha \to \beta$}
\newunicodechar{}{\ensuremath{abc + d\cdot f(x) = g_i}}
\newunicodechar{}{$\Phi = \phi(x,n)$;}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{Julia}
 : number
# xyz
function 
 


 
  
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Almost there.