# Applying a style to all math blocks in an environment

Tags: math-mode

I'm writing a math paper, and I want to change the style for the statement of theorems to `\tt`. However, I want this to affect things within math mode as well as normal text. Is there some way to force all math blocks within an environment to change style?

Comment: See the command `\everymath` which can be redefined at the beginning of every theorem env. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62978/can-i-change-all-math-output-to-use-monospaced-text

Comment: Note that `\tt` is deprecated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one possible solution implementing the idea proposed by **Marco Daniel** in a comment; the solution uses:

1. The [`amsthm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) package to define a new theorem style to produce theorem-like structures with heading and body text in monospaced font. This style is used to define a `theo` environment.
2. The [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to append [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63000/3954) to [Can I change all math output to use monospaced text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62978/3954)
   to a hook executed by the `\begin` command at the beginning of the `theo` environmet.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsthm}
   \usepackage{etoolbox}

   \newtheoremstyle{monosp}
     {\topsep}{\topsep}
     {\ttfamily}{}
     {\ttfamily}{.\mbox{$ $}}
     {.5em}{}
   \theoremstyle{monosp}
   \newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

   \AtBeginEnvironment{theo}{%
   \everymath{\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}
   \everydisplay{\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}
   }

   \begin{document}

   Some test text $a=b$ and some in-line math $c=d$ and a displayed expression
   \[a=b\]
   just to test.
   \begin{theo}
   Some test text $a=b$ and some in-line math $c=d$ and a displayed expression
   \[a=b\]
   just to test.
   \end{theo}
   Some test text $a=b$ and some in-line math $c=d$ and a displayed expression
   \[a=b\]
   just to test.

   \end{document}
   ```

[image]