# Monospace font in cases environment

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, cases, typewriter

I have this code:

```
\[
text
\begin{cases}
text, text \rightarrow text\\
text \rightarrow text, text, text, text text
\end{cases}
\]
...
\[
text
\begin{cases}
text text \rightarrow text, text text, text\\
text, text \rightarrow text
\end{cases}
\]
...
```

There is a way to format the entire text in monospace font? Something like this:

```
\[
\mathtt{text}
\begin{cases}
\mathtt{text, text} \rightarrow \mathtt{text}\\
\mathtt{text} \rightarrow \mathtt{text, text, text, text text}
\end{cases}
\]
...
\[
\mathtt{text}
\begin{cases}
\mathtt{text text} \rightarrow \mathtt{text, text text, text}\\
\mathtt{text, text} \rightarrow \mathtt{text}
\end{cases}
\]
...
```

but avoiding the repetition of the `\mathtt` command.

I've tried the solution [proposed here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62978/can-i-change-all-math-output-to-use-monospaced-text) but it doesn't work for me: font doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `cases` environment is particularly well suited for the job at hand, especially as the material that needs to be typeset doesn't appear to be all that math-y -- except, maybe, for the `\rightarrow` directives.

I would use a `tabular` environment, with `\left\{` before the `tabular` environment and `\right.` after it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\[
\texttt{text}
\left\{ \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\ttfamily}l@{}}
   text, text $\to$ text\\
   text $\to$ text, text, text, text text\\
\end{tabular} \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\ttfamily}l@{}}`

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks, have updated the code shown in the answer.